# Getting an integer atomic vector (vs. numeric)

Tags: r

I am forming a data.frame from character data that is not under my
control (from an API). I would like the resulting variables to get their
most natural class with minimal fuss. Specifically, I want integer
variables, not numeric, when appropriate.

I am digging this data out of XML and one attribute -- let's call it
`attA` -- presents integers as integers, i.e. with no period and
trailing zero. Another attribute -- let's call it `attB` -- is more
generally useful and correct, but always presents numbers with one
decimal place, even if that is uniformly zero. (The data could also be character, mind you!)

My initial approach was based on `attA` and processing through
`type.convert()` but now I want to use `attB`. From reading the
`type.convert()` docs, I'm surprised it does not produce integers when
all the data could be represented as integer. Am I misreading that? Any
suggestions on how to get what I want without doing some unholy
processing of the character data?

```
attA <- c("1", "2")
str(type.convert(attA))
#>  int [1:2] 1 2

attB <- c("1.0", "2.0")
str(type.convert(attB))
#>  num [1:2] 1 2

unholy <- gsub("\\.0$", "", attB)
str(type.convert(unholy))
#>  int [1:2] 1 2
```

Relevant bit of `type.convert()` docs: "Given a character vector, it
attempts to convert it to logical, integer, numeric or complex, and
failing that converts it to factor unless as.is = TRUE. The first type
that can accept all the non-missing values is chosen... Vectors
containing optional whitespace followed by decimal constants
representable as R integers or values from na.strings are converted to
integer."

Comment: Any reason why you can't replace `type.convert()` with `as.integer()`?  `as.integer(attB)` works well.  Also `read.table()` could possibly be used, and you can specify `colClasses` there.

Comment: In general, I do not know if the data will be integer only, numeric, or even character. I really want that hierarchy of logical, integer, numeric, character to be applied literally (I always use `type.convert(..., as.is = FALSE)`). That's why I can't use `as.integer()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From reading the `type.convert()` docs, I'm surprised it does not
>   produce integers when all the data could be represented as integer. Am
>   I misreading that?

I think you may be.

In some contexts, converting a number written as `123.0` to `123` does change its meaning: the trailing zero in `123.0` *can* be intended to indicate that it represents a value measured to a higher degree of precision (e.g. to the nearest tenth) than `123` (which may only have been measured to the nearest integral value). ([See Wikipedia's article on significant figures for a fuller explanation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures#Rules_more_fully_explained)) So `type.convert()` takes the appropriate/conservative approach of treating `123.0` (and indeed `123.`) as representing numeric rather than integer values.

As a solution, how about something like this?

```
type.convert2 <- function(x) {
    x <- sub("(^\\d+)\\.0*$", "\\1", x)
    type.convert(x)
}

class(type.convert2("123.1"))
# [1] "numeric"
class(type.convert2("123.0"))
# [1] "integer"
class(type.convert2("123."))
# [1] "integer"

class(type.convert2("hello.0"))
# [1] "factor"
type.convert2("hello.0")
# [1] hello.0
# Levels: hello.0
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be testing against values after they are coerced to integers,

```
res <- type.convert(attB)
if (isTRUE(all.equal((tmp <- as.integer(res)), res))) res <- tmp
```

Another possibility could be using `trunc` to test against truncated values.

`type.convert` won't convert the strings to integers because it uses `strtol` function in C, which stops at the ".".  Then, in the R source, you see this [line](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/utils/src/io.c#L164), where `res` is the converted string resulting from `strtol`,

```
if (*endp != '\0') res = NA_INTEGER;
```

It means, if the entire string wasn't valid, then it isn't an integer.

Comment: Thanks for digging down to the source! Helpful to know exactly why the mere presence of the "." will have integer vs. numeric consequences.